# GlassFish extending JARs used by common classloader

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, classloader

I am migrating several applications from JBoss 4 to GlassFish 3.1.x.  Each of these application use the same API that provides common classes and interfaces that each of the applications uses.  Let's call it `CoreAPI.jar`.

`CoreAPI.jar` is put into the `<domain>/lib` directory of GlassFish and is loaded by the common class loader.

Now let's say that each application extends a class (not abstract) from the CoreAPI called `Version`:

```
public class Version {
    public String getVersion() { return null; }
}
```

The method `getVersion()` is called from within the API itself in several places and each application that uses the API is responsible for extending the class and providing a version like so:

```
public class MyAppVersion extends Version {
    private static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @Override
    public String getVersion() { return VERSION; }
}
```

When I deploy the application to GlassFish, bundled in a WAR or EAR, any time the API calls `getVersion()` from the parent class, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` - it cannot seem to find the sub-class.

The sub-class is found properly if `CoreAPI.jar` is bundled with the WAR and removed from `<domain>/lib` directory, but I cannot do this because many application require it as a shared library.

Is there a way I can make a shared-library 'see' a sub-class within a deployed application?

Thanks!

**Clarification:**  I do NOT have access to change the CoreAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can make a shared-library 'see' a sub-class within a
>   deployed application?

No. The application class loader is a descendant of the common class loader, and class loaders can only see their parents, not their dependents.

This is typically discovered when the common class tries to do something like `Class.forName("com.app.ImplementationClass")` in code that is actually within common library.

Comment: Is there a way around this?  I have a similar setup with a Websphere 7 server (using shared library references) and my case is working OK.  What is the difference in the class loaders?

Comment: There can be a lot of differences in class loaders. I'm not familiar enough with Websphere to comment. But, for example, in a Glassfish EAR, by default, all of the classes and jars of ALL of the modules (EJBs, WARs, etc.) are combined in to a single, shared space. Specifically if an EAR contains 2 WARs, WAR A will see classes and libs in WAR B. Other app servers do that differently (isolating the WARs), even though both ways are in spec with the standard. So there can be lots of differences. You should look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beadf.html for details on GF.

Comment: Thanks!  I've read through the class loader hierarchy several times now; and I have put the `CoreAPI.jar` in several different locations of the class loader.  Still no luck.  Sadly, I guess that 'No' is the correct answer to my question.  My guess is that the API will need to be rewritten..

Answer (score 1):

In order to share libraries between all applications you should use the `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib` folder. When you install add-ons to GlassFish via the Update Tool you may even notice it copies third-party jars to this folder so it will be available to all apps.

To share in all applications under a domain you mais put it in`$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/your-domain/lib` folder, as you did.

To test what you described I've created 2 maven projects:

- A java project called version (the mock of your CoreAPI)
- A web project called web-version (the guy that will extend the CoreAPI)

The java project contains what would be your non-abstract CoreAPI class:

```
package com.acme.version;

public class Version
{
    public String getVersion() { return null; }
}
```

In the web-version project I add a provided scope dependency to the `version-1.0.jar` so it may be compiled, but it will not be added to the project once it will be present in the Glassfish /lib folder.

Then the web-version project has the extended version of the `Version` class that I used for the test:

```
package com.acme.web.controller;

import com.acme.version.Version;

public class ExtendedVersion extends Version
{
    private static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @Override
    public String getVersion ()
    {
        return VERSION;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getVersion();
    }
}
```

Then I did this:

- Built the version project and copied the resulting jar to the `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib`  folder as mentioned above.
- Created a controller containing an `ExtendedVersion` instance and deployed the app. It outputs `1.0` in a web page.

> Is there a way I can make a shared-library 'see' a sub-class within a deployed application?

Well, it is a little odd because the shared-library is being loaded. It seems that for some reason your subclass is not. (Are there any other relevant exceptions in the logs?)

I think by the little bit you've described that this problem may even be related to other dependencies you had with JBoss x GlassFish transition, not with your approach on subclassing or classloading.

Comment: Hi and thanks for testing this.  I think the difference is that the API itself is calling `getVersion()` from the `Version` parent and is expecting it to return the sub-class override